# Performance of canvas in xcode simulator with retina display

Tags: xcode, ipad, html, canvas, ios-simulator

I have an html5 canvas game, limited to 30FPS. This runs fine (@30FPS) on the iPad2 and the xcode simulator when set to iPad2.

However, when I set the simulator to "Retina" and run the app the FPS drop to 11FPS. I get roughly the same result when I do the following:

- Let the simulator scale up my iPad2 images.
- When I use CSS transorms to scale up my images.
- when I JS to scale up my images (using pixelratio).

Interestingly, this 11FPS is also seen when I test it in the iPhone retina simulator (even though this app isn't built for the iPhone so it simply gets cut-off).

Are there any known issues with canvas and the xcode simulator? Are there any fixes or am I doing something wrong?

My hardware is Macbook Pro (mid 2012) with i7CPU and 8GB ram.

Thanks
J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simulator not an emulator, never expect accurate results from it, especially when it comes to hardware performance related issues. Test your app on a real device, if you get the desired frame rate on a real device, that is all that matters.

Now, why your simulator is doing this is somewhat interesting. My best guess is that the computer is having a hard time running your game at a higher resolution than your screen in a scaled down window... Once again, just my best guess.

Comment: `It's a simulator not an emulator` is probably the answer. It runs just as slow on the simulator for the iPhone4s (retina) but runs absolutely fine (60FPS) on the actual iphone4s device.